# flutter - how to create voice record in popup when click mic image using flutter?

Tags: flutter

[image]

mic image code

```
Center(
                   child: Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 1),
                              child: IconButton(
                                iconSize: 45,
                                icon: Ink.image(
                                  image: const AssetImage('assets/mic.png'),
                                ),
                                onPressed: () {
                                  // do something when the button is pressed
                                  Navigator.push(
                                    context,
                                    MaterialPageRoute(
                                        builder: (context) =>
                                            Recorder12Screen()),
                                  );
                                  // RecorderDialogScreen(context);
                                },
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
```

when click this mic image I want display voice recording page as a pop up window.
recording page image... my output

[image]

But I wanna like this

[image]

I my voice recording function has 2 pages

[image]

and this

[image]

2nd page is then the click pause button then display playback page

both pages I wanna display as pop up windows

1st page

[image]

2nd page
[image]

1st page code

```
import 'package:firebase_storage/firebase_storage.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:kathana/screens/voiceRecord/voiceRecord12/recorder/feature_buttons_view.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

import '../../../provider/sign_in_provider.dart';

class Recorder12Screen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<Recorder12Screen> createState() => _Recorder12ScreenState();
}

class _Recorder12ScreenState extends State<Recorder12Screen> {
  String? downloadURL;
  List<Reference> references = [];
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _onUploadComplete();
  }

  //snack bar for  showing error
  showSnackBar(String snackText, Duration d) {
    final snackBar = SnackBar(content: Text(snackText), duration: d);
    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final sp = context.read<SignInProvider>();
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            flex: 2,
            child: FeatureButtonsView(
              onUploadComplete: _onUploadComplete,
            ),
          ),
          Text(
            "${sp.uid}",
            style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 12, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<void> _onUploadComplete() async {
    final sp = context.read<SignInProvider>();
    FirebaseStorage firebaseStorage = FirebaseStorage.instance;
    ListResult listResult = await firebaseStorage
        .ref()
        .child("${sp.uid}/records")
        .child("voices")
        .list();
    setState(() {
      references = listResult.items;
    });
  }
}
```

2nd page code

```
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:audioplayers/audioplayers.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_storage/firebase_storage.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_audio_recorder2/flutter_audio_recorder2.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

import '../../../../provider/sign_in_provider.dart';

class FeatureButtonsView extends StatefulWidget {
  final Function onUploadComplete;

  FeatureButtonsView({
    Key? key,
    required this.onUploadComplete,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _FeatureButtonsViewState createState() => _FeatureButtonsViewState();

  String? userId;
}

class _FeatureButtonsViewState extends State<FeatureButtonsView> {
  late bool _isPlaying;
  late bool _isUploading;
  late bool _isRecorded;
  late bool _isRecording;

  late AudioPlayer _audioPlayer;
  late String _filePath;

  late FlutterAudioRecorder2 _audioRecorder;
  Future getData() async {
    final sp = context.read<SignInProvider>();
    sp.getDataFromSharedPreferences();
  }

  String downloadUrl = '';

  Future<void> onsend() async {
    //uploading to cloudfirestore
    FirebaseFirestore firebaseFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
    final sp = context.read<SignInProvider>();
    await firebaseFirestore
        .collection("users")
        .doc("${sp.uid}")
        .collection("reco")
        .add({'downloadURL': downloadUrl}).whenComplete(() =>
            showSnackBar("Voice uploaded successful", Duration(seconds: 2)));
  }

  //snackbar for  showing error
  showSnackBar(String snackText, Duration d) {
    final snackBar = SnackBar(content: Text(snackText), duration: d);
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _isPlaying = false;
    _isUploading = false;
    _isRecorded = false;
    _isRecording = false;
    _audioPlayer = AudioPlayer();
    final sp = context.read<SignInProvider>();
    FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("users")
        .doc(sp.uid)
        .get()
        .then((value) {
      setState(() {});
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: _isRecorded
          ? _isUploading
              ? Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
                        child: LinearProgressIndicator()),
                    Text('Uplaoding to Firebase'),
                  ],
                )
              : Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    IconButton(
                      icon: Icon(Icons.replay),
                      onPressed: _onRecordAgainButtonPressed,
                    ),
                    IconButton(
                      icon: Icon(_isPlaying ? Icons.pause : Icons.play_arrow),
                      onPressed: _onPlayButtonPressed,
                    ),
                    IconButton(
                      icon: Icon(Icons.upload_file, color: Colors.green),
                      onPressed: _onFileUploadButtonPressed,
                    ),
                  ],
                )
          : IconButton(
              icon: _isRecording
                  ? Icon(Icons.pause)
                  : Icon(Icons.fiber_manual_record),
              onPressed: _onRecordButtonPressed,
            ),
    );
  }

  Future<void> _onFileUploadButtonPressed() async {
    FirebaseStorage firebaseStorage = FirebaseStorage.instance;

    setState(() {
      _isUploading = true;
    });
    try {
      final sp = context.read<SignInProvider>();
      Reference ref = firebaseStorage.ref().child("${sp.uid}/records1").child(
          _filePath.substring(_filePath.lastIndexOf('/'), _filePath.length));
      TaskSnapshot uploadedFile = await ref.putFile(File(_filePath));

      if (uploadedFile.state == TaskState.success) {
        downloadUrl = await ref.getDownloadURL();
      }
      widget.onUploadComplete();
      onsend(); //send downloadURL after get it
    } catch (error) {
      print('Error occured while uplaoding to Firebase ${error.toString()}');
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
        SnackBar(
          content: Text('Error occured while uplaoding'),
        ),
      );
    } finally {
      setState(() {
        _isUploading = false;
      });
    }
  }

  void _onRecordAgainButtonPressed() {
    setState(() {
      _isRecorded = false;
    });
  }

  Future<void> _onRecordButtonPressed() async {
    if (_isRecording) {
      _audioRecorder.stop();
      _isRecording = false;
      _isRecorded = true;
    } else {
      _isRecorded = false;
      _isRecording = true;

      await _startRecording();
    }
    setState(() {});
  }

  void _onPlayButtonPressed() {
    if (!_isPlaying) {
      _isPlaying = true;

      _audioPlayer.play(_filePath, isLocal: true);
      _audioPlayer.onPlayerCompletion.listen((duration) {
        setState(() {
          _isPlaying = false;
        });
      });
    } else {
      _audioPlayer.pause();
      _isPlaying = false;
    }
    setState(() {});
  }

  Future<void> _startRecording() async {
    final bool? hasRecordingPermission =
        await FlutterAudioRecorder2.hasPermissions;

    if (hasRecordingPermission ?? false) {
      Directory directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
      String filepath = directory.path +
          '/' +
          DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch.toString() +
          '.aac';
      _audioRecorder =
          FlutterAudioRecorder2(filepath, audioFormat: AudioFormat.AAC);
      await _audioRecorder.initialized;
      _audioRecorder.start();
      _filePath = filepath;
      setState(() {});
    } else {
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
          content: Center(child: Text('Please enable recording permission'))));
    }
  }
}
```

Those 2 pages, how convert to like as a popup?
**My voice recording functions work perfectly I'm asking to convert those two material pages to like  popup windows.**

Answer (score 0):

You can use this package for recording the voice :

```
dependencies:
  flutter_sound: ^9.2.13
```

Comment: my voice recording functions are working perfectly. I'm asking convert material pages like as popup windows